# AWS SNS (SMS) : special character randomly replaced by a dot (not always, just sometimes)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sms

When I try to send an SMS with AWS SNS with a special character, it sometimes (not always) replace this character with a dot (.).

For exemple when I try to send `Œufs` (eggs in french), I receive on my phone number : `.ufs`(and sometimes `Œufs`)

Is it normal? Do I need to configure anything?

FYI : I use AWS-SDK (Nodejs) into a Lambda

Thanks !